# Data horizontally in a select multiselect

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment

Is there any way (perhaps with css style) to change the orientation of data from a select (html) from horizontal to vertical direction to stay with multiselect? I tried with jquery but I do not think something like that.

Expected Result:
[Click here to view the image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0UL0-6YseY8NlUteGd2dkw3YUU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: what you have done? Add your code..

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done.

`SELECT` is closely tied to the OS and cannot be fully styled with CSS the way other elements are.

You would need a JavaScript-based "select replacement" that uses a styled UL/LI structure to do what you want.